# Unnecessary repaint of following siblings

Tags: css, transform, transition, repaint

I'm using [react-transitive-number](https://github.com/Lapple/react-transitive-number) to achieve transitive animation of number changes [[demo page]](http://lapple.github.io/react-transitive-number/)
[image]

The problem is - if you look [this page](http://lapple.github.io/react-transitive-number/) in Chrome devtools, "Paint Flashing" in Rendering tab you may see that every transition cause following siblings to repaint.

[image]

Why this might happen? I can understand repaint of number, or any element relates to this plugin. But why it affects following siblings at whole website?
Are there any way to avoid these unnecessary repaints?

Comment: You're using the same demo no? Have you double checked all the variables, etc, are the same?

Comment: I made this gif at official demo page of that plugin

Comment: Weird. For me the demo page works fine, without repainting. What broswer and version are you using?

Comment: do you have keys on your elements? just an idea

Comment: Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6

Comment: @bitten what do you meant by keys?

Comment: i don't think keys are necessary, i misunderstood. keys are a way to help react smartly re render your app when you are rendering a list of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving every tag with number to own layer solved problem.
Solution is - adding of

`translateZ(0)`